# Сокеты. Как правильно написать сервер?

Tags: сокеты

Как правильно написать сервер для работы с несколькими клиентами через сокеты (с++, линукс) ?

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего для каждого входящего соединения fd = accept(), потом fork() и работа в потомке с fd. В родителе close(fd). Это простой многопроцессный сервер.

Но, вариантов много.

Можно делать новый поток для каждого fd

или сделать пул потоков и очередь fd к пулу (освободившийся поток не завершается, а возвращается в пул при окончании обработки соединения)

или сделать пул процессов и передавать fd через sendmsg()

или синхронно, используя select(), обрабатывать как новые соединения, так и данные клиента в одном процессе

Зависит от задачи.

Comment: Нашёл по ссылке http://www.rsdn.ru/article/unix/sockets.xml пример сервера (Листинг 2. Эхо-сервер.), вот отрывок:
...
while(1)
    {
        sock = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
        if(sock < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(3);
        }

        while(1)
        {
            bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);
            if(bytes_read <= 0) break;
            send(sock, buf, bytes_read, 0);
        }
    
        close(sock);
    }
...
соединились, отослали, считали и закрыли. А как переписать так, чтобы один раз открыли сокет и потом постоянно общаемся?

Comment: @sofen, упрощенно (без обработки ошибок, логгинга и т.п.)

    while(1) { 
        sock = accept(...); // новый клиент
        if (fork()) {
            int status;
            close(sock); 
            while(waitpid(-1,&status,WHOHANG) > 0); // подберем zombies
        } else { 
            // новый child (их здесь м.б. много)
            while(1) { 
                // здесь общаетесь recv(sock), send() ...
            }
            close(sock); 
            exit(0); // конец дочернего процесса
        }
    }

Почитайте внимательней про accept()